# baseUrl issue - requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, blueimp

I am experiencing a baseUrl issue, I get a 404 error, telling me `root-app/js/module.js` is not found. Here's how it comes

First, I call

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/requireJs/require.js"></script>
```

then in `js/main.js`, I have (for testing mean)

```
require({
    paths: {
        upload: 'js/vendor/module.min'
    }
}, ['js/vendor/main.js'], function(App) {
    App.add(2, 2);
});
```

But in `js/vendor/module.min.js` itself, there are some declarations as `define(["module"]...`, and they are the one that trigger the 404 error. How can I circumvent the problem ? (Sure, I can move my `js/vendor/module.min` to `js/module.min` but I want to keep my code organized ;). So is it necessary to change `define(["module"]...` into `define(["vendor/module"]...` ?

Comment: this syntax of putting the paths config in the require call itself is foreign to me. Generally you call require.config once with paths, baseUrl etc and then it works for all future require() and define() calls. Have you tried that approach? Apart from that, I'm not clear on what you're asking.

Comment: @explunit, thnaks, I found my problem, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem was here

```
paths: {
        upload: 'js/vendor/module.min'
    }
```

because of declaration `define(["module"]` in `js/vendor/module.min.js` suppose I can't rename the path as `uplaod`, it is expecting this

```
paths: {
            module: 'js/vendor/module.min'
        }
```